# Scrolltop horizontal start point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGLZoR

My "floating div" follows the page scroll - it does this immediately after moving the scroll bar down. How do I only start the floating when a px (lets say 200px) scroll height has been reached. So when you scroll down 200px the floating div can be seen rather than straight away.

```
                $(window).scroll(function(){
                   $("#div").stop().animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px", "marginLeft":($(window).scrollLeft()) + "px"}, "slow" );
                });
```

EDIT:

The div must return to the original position when scrolling back up to the top - past the 200px mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Try this instead

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop){
        if($(window).scrollTop()>200){
            $("#div").stop().animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px", "marginLeft":($(window).scrollLeft()) + "px"}, "slow" );
        }
    } else {
        $("#div").stop().animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px", "marginLeft":($(window).scrollLeft()) + "px"}, "slow" );
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

This will check whether you're going 'up' od 'down' and on down it will scroll past 200px, but on up it will scroll normally :)

Comment: Yes tried that one, when you scroll back to the top the div stays at the 200 mark rather than resetting back at the top